# Jenkins job failing with Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: checkout -f returned status code -1

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running Jenkins on windows and trying to download the code from Git through jenkins, the following error occurs. I tried configuring the "Additional Behaviours" to 'Advance clone behaviours' with options - 'shallow clone' and 'Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations :60' but still the job is failing with below error

Checking out Revision c340e8f017689f723b19c2b479d7db7c3e66591d (origin/develop)

> c:\programs\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   c:\programs\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f c340e8f017689f723b19c2b479d7db7c3e66591d

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
FATAL: Could not checkout c340e8f017689f723b19c2b479d7db7c3e66591d
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout c340e8f017689f723b19c2b479d7db7c3e66591d
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2031)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to jenkins10(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor559.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1033)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "c:\programs\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f c340e8f017689f723b19c2b479d7db7c3e66591d" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$800(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2023)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Looks to be a known issue from the github plugin in Jenkins. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26290

Comment: Try to diagnose by launching Jenkins with "-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true" . It will help you to understand the root cause of the error.

Comment: @dildeepak : Thank you for the response. I am pretty new to the jenkins, can you please direct me where i can add "- Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true" parameter, will this provide the high level logging for the issue? I didn't find any concrete solutions, do you recommend installing latest Jenkins/Git plugins, my current Git Plugin is 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @dildeepak advice and I found that my problem was git was complaining on long file names.

```
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to create file Referenced Packages/CloudSense Contract Lifecycle Management Data Model/layouts/Document_Template_Section_Association__c-Document Template%2FSection Association 
Layout.layout: Filename too long
```

To find out what the root cause for your problem is, do the following

> Stop Jenkins

Edit

```
JENKINS_INSTALL_FOLDER/jenkins.xml
```

Add `-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true` to `<arguments>` tag

```
<arguments>...... -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true</arguments>
```

> Start Jenkins

Now run your build job, and look at the console output for more detailed error message. You will spot the root cause.